# Grey out optionbuttons when a specific option button is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I asked a similar question this morning and i got a great answer, but then i pushed a little bit further and this is where i'm kinda stuck.

This is my initial post : [Unselect an entire optionbutton group if another optionbutton outside the group is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018190/unselect-an-entire-optionbutton-group-if-another-optionbutton-outside-the-group/60018447?noredirect=1#comment106146898_60018447)

But now, I would like to have this:

If `OptionButton1.Value = True` or `OptionButton2.Value = True` then Grey out `OptionButton4` to `OptionButton11` (Also gave it a group name : "Category").

But, If `OptionButton3.Value = True`, then it ungreys the `OptionButton4` to `OptionButton11` (Group Category).

**EDIT:**

I did something and it worked but once I run my userform and generate a number (userform purpose), the optionbuttons stay greyed out. Here's the code i used :

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    OptionButton4.Enabled = False
    OptionButton5.Enabled = False
    OptionButton6.Enabled = False
    OptionButton7.Enabled = False
    OptionButton8.Enabled = False
    OptionButton9.Enabled = False
    OptionButton10.Enabled = False
    OptionButton11.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()   
    OptionButton4.Enabled = False
    OptionButton5.Enabled = False
    OptionButton6.Enabled = False
    OptionButton7.Enabled = False
    OptionButton8.Enabled = False
    OptionButton9.Enabled = False
    OptionButton10.Enabled = False
    OptionButton11.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2:**

My solution for now is to add

```
Unload Me
UserForm1.Show
```

so it reset my userform and remove the greyed optionbuttons

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you solved your own issue. Another would be to create a validation sub that would actually check everything every time an option is selected. Also there is a way to access all the forms controls something like Forms('myform').controls('mycontrol') I admit I am rusty but if you iterate through you can disable enable as wanted and call that on load

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of unloading and reloading the form, handle the enabling/disabling.
2. Create a common procedure to handle the enabling/disabling so that you do not have to duplicate the code.
3. You can loop through all the controls which will not only reduce the lines of the code but will be easier to maintain.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    EnableOptBtns False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    EnableOptBtns False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    EnableOptBtns True
End Sub

Private Sub EnableOptBtns(enable As Boolean)
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 4 To 11
        Me.Controls("OptionButton" & i).Enabled = enable
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yes That's what I want and your way works too. The only problem is, when i Generate my number in my UserForm, The userform is suppose to resets so I can use the userform again, but the optionbutton stay greyed out! This is why I used `unload me`. And your way doesnt ungrey them after a first utilisation.... Maybe it's not working because i Didnt use your `Option Explicit` ? and only the code after that?

Comment: `The userform is suppose to resets` You can reset the option buttons by using `EnableOptBtns True`. You can reset it in a commnadbutton or from whereever you want. No need to unload and reload it